# How to update the verion of a exisiting maven package

Tags: java, maven, version, lifecycle

we use maven to build a java project, but it is not able to release it immediately due to leak of tests. therefor we use a version like 1.2.3-aphla. after all tests are passed (which takes long time), we want to change the version from 1.2.3-alpha to 1.2.3-release. is there any way to change the version of a existing maven package directly without to build it again with the specified new version?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot change the version before the tests. Also you will always have to build the artifact if you want to publish them but maybe you can just skip the tests with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: we use confidence gate for the maven build like "-dev", "-alpha", "-release". A maven package which is verified by the unit tests will get the -dev label, if all smoke test are passed, we label it with -alpha. only if all e2e tests are passed, we label the package with -release. it taks many days to run all the tests.